# TableView separator cells disappearing?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, cells

I've developed a personality quiz app here entirely in code. Some of the separators keep disappearing though - it's not consistent from question to question, but it's usually one or two in the middle.

[image]

I can update with code, but I'm not sure what aspect of TableView's code is causing this problem.

Comment: Hi. It's hard to tell form just an image. But from the top of my head, I think this could be a constraint problem. Check if you're getting any Auto-layout errors on the console. Also, if you are testing on a simulator, check if it's still happening while testing on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you take the screen shot from the simulator ? if it's from simulator, it's normal, as the mac book don't have enough pixel to display the separator. 
change your simulator to iPhone 8 would be fine.

Comment: Yep, looks like it's just the simulator - I was in iPad, but it works fine on iPhone 8.